# $2x^6 + y^4 = 9xy$ at the point $(1, 2)$

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

Find the equation of the tangent line to the curve $2x^6 + y^4 = 9xy$ at the point $(1, 2)$.

Can someone help me on this question, I am super confused and I have no clue where to start. I know the derivative of the equation is $12x^5 + 4y^3 = 9$ but after that I am lost. I plugged in $12*1+4*8$ but it is not $9$.

Please help

Comment: You say you have differentiated the equation, but your derivative is incorrect. A fundamental question is, what variable are you differentiating with respect to? You seem to be attempting to do it simultaneously in $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @K K Lorence. You know the derivaitve is $12x^5+4y^3=9$ What makes you think that this is correct?

Comment: Translate the equation $2(x+1)^6+(y+2)^4=9(x+1)(y+2)$ taking $(1,2)$ to the origin. Use the binomial theorem to get the lower order terms, i.e. take the tangent cone: $2( 6\cdot 1^5 x+1^6)+(4\cdot 2^3 y+2^4)=9(2x+y+2).$ Note that the constant term vanishes (the point is on the curve). Simplify and translate back: $23(y-2)=6(x-1),$ and you have your tangent.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing called "the derivative of the equation". You can not take "derivatives" of an equation; you take "derivatives" for *functions*.

The equation $2x^6+y^4=9xy$ [implicitly define a function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function) $y=f(x)$ near the point $(1,2)$. The derivative of this function $f$ at $x=1$ would give you the slope of the tangent line. Once you find out the derivative $f'(1)$, then the equation for the tangent line would be
$$
y-2=f'(1)(x-1)\;\tag{0}
$$

In order the find $f'(1)$, you use [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation) as follows:
$$
12x^5+4y^3y'=9(y+xy')\tag{1}
$$
where $y'=f'(x)$. Solving (1), you get
$$
y'=\frac{12x^5-9y}{9x-4y^3}\tag{2}
$$
Substituting $(x,y)=(1,2)$ into (2), you get the value of $f'(1)$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by assuming that $y$ is a function of $x$. This is important, as $\frac{d}{dx}y^n = ny^{n-1}y'$ by the chain rule. Thus, differentiating your equation, we get:
$$\frac{d}{dx} (2x^6+y^4)=9\frac{d}{dx}(xy)$$
$$12x^5+4y^3y'=9y+9xy'$$
$$12x^5-9y=9xy'-4y^3y'$$
$$12x^5-9y=y'(9x-4y^3)$$
$$y'=\frac{12x^5-9y}{(9x-4y^3)}$$
Substituting $x=1$ and $y=2$ from the given point, we find that
$$y'=\frac{6}{23}$$
All that is left is to apply point-slope form to find the equation of the tangent line
$$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$$
$$y-2 = \frac{6}{23}(x-1)$$
$$y = \frac{6}{23}(x-1) + 2$$
$$y = \frac{6x}{23} + \frac{40}{23}$$